# WSO2 DSS/ESB services starting in network card and wrong address

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server

Services dss and esb are rising with the IP address of the external network, 
need the services come up with the address of the internal card.
Where can I set to start on the board with the internal address ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `HostName` and `MgtHostName` in `repository/conf/carbon.xml` to desired IP or Hostname.

```
<HostName>127.0.0.1</HostName>
<MgtHostName>127.0.0.1</MgtHostName>
```

Then replace every occurrence of `${carbon.local.ip}` in every config file, with desired IP or hostname.